# from an expression to a language object

Tags: r

I would like to use `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()`, but with arguments in the `...` that I programatically construct, with strings.

Example :

```
# classic way
microbenchmark(head(1:1e6), head(1:1e8), times = 10) # (interesting...)
# define my arguments
functionStrings <- lapply(c(6,8), function(ni) paste0("head(1:1e", ni, ")"))
# will not work
do.call(microbenchmark, lapply(functionStrings, function(vi) parse(text=vi)))
```

The problem here is that `microbenchmark` works with unevaluated expressions, of class "language", that it then `deparse()`. Doing `deparse()` on a normal expression unfortunately deparse the expression object...

```
bla <- quote(head(1:1e6))
blou <- parse(text = "head(1:1e6)")
eval(bla) ; eval(blou) # Same thing, but....
deparse(bla)
deparse(parse(text = "head(1:1e6)"))
```

How to get from a string or an expression (argument or output of `parse()` above) to a language object (output of quote() above) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anonymous function in the last line of the first block of code should be:

```
function(vi) parse(text=vi)[[1]]
```

That is:

- the argument to `parse` is named `text` and not `test` and
- a call object is needed rather than an expression so use `[[1]]` .

Comment: Thanks, that made the trick! beautiful. (+ I corrected the typo, thanks for pointing it out)